# DateTime.UtcNow Not Change, Why?

Tags: .net, windows, utc, systemtime

check the code

```
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(2010, 1, 1));
            ulong timestamp = (ulong)(t.TotalMilliseconds * 100000000);
            s.Append("<li>" + timestamp.ToString());
        }
```

You will get same result 100 times, it means the DateTime.UtcNow never changes even I multiply milliseconds by 100000000 times.

Is here anyone know how to get fresh DateTime.UtcNow each time?

Comment: As suggestion, I now use code:             for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                s.Append("<li>" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString());
            } still no difference, all same string, why? Is there some other setting in whole asp.net project?

Comment: anyway, I need to get something as rowkey, so is here anyway to get UNIQUE string by time, except the way that puts some random number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such a tight loop chances are indeed good that you will be getting the same time.

Each tick in the [`Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) property represent a 100 nano-second slice. Your code would iterate faster than that.

Comment: The system timer runs with 16-ms resolution.

Comment: Finally, I use ticks plus some random digits after it for a rowkey, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I just put your snippet in LinqPad and added a `t.TotalMilliseconds.Dump()` right before the end of the for loop, here are the first few results:

```
61068982141.4911    
61068982143.9916    
61068982143.9916    
61068982144.4917    
61068982144.4917    
61068982144.4917    
61068982144.4917    
61068982144.9918    
61068982144.9918    
61068982144.9918    
61068982144.9918    
61068982145.4919    
61068982145.4919    
61068982145.4919    
61068982145.4919    
61068982145.992    
61068982145.992    
61068982145.992    
61068982145.992
```

The loop is executing rather fast, you're seeing fractional ms there after the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class to measure the time span with high resolution.  On most computers the default clock interval is 15.625 ms, which means within a clock interval the difference of two timestamps retrieved using `DateTime.UtcNow` will be 0.  `Stopwatch` uses perf counter whenever available (i.e. on most PCs) and the resolution is usually less than 1 us.  See [Time Span Measurement in Managed Code](http://imperfect.work/2016/05/14/time-span-measurement/) for more details.